# Material Ui TablePagination isnt working with ny array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

my TablePagination isnt changing the rows at each page of my table and not even limitating the rows with the row filter. Actually Im thinking that can be beacause im building the table with a mapping of an array like that:

```
    0:[name : Robert, age: 15, sons:{ 0:{ name: RobertSon, age 28} 1:{ name: RobertDaugther, 
    age:14}]
1:[name : Robert, age: 15, sons:{ 0:{ name: RobertSon, age 28} 1:{ name: RobertDaugther, 
    age:14}]
2:[name : Robert, age: 15, sons:{ 0:{ name: RobertSon, age 28} 1:{ name: RobertDaugther, 
    age:14}]
```

and here is my code actually

```
<TableContainer style={{ padding: 0 }}>
      <TableToolbar
        // onUserAdd={setOpenUserDialog}
        filterOptions={filterOptions}
        setFilterOptions={setFilterOptions}
        searchTerm={searchTerm}
        setSearchTerm={setSearchTerm}
        // selected={selected}
        // setSelected={setSelected}
      />
      <Table className={classes.table} aria-label="customized table">
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <StyledTableCell />
            <StyledTableCell align="center"> RECEBIDAS ÚTEIS</StyledTableCell>
            <StyledTableCell colSpan={2} align="center">
              {' '}
              ATENDIDAS
            </StyledTableCell>
            <StyledTableCell colSpan={2} align="center">
              {' '}
              ABANDONADAS ÚTEIS
            </StyledTableCell>
            <StyledTableCell colSpan={2} align="center">
              {' '}
              ABANDONADAS ÚNICAS
            </StyledTableCell>
            <StyledTableCell colSpan={2} align="center">
              {' '}
              AUTO RECUPERADAS
            </StyledTableCell>
            <StyledTableCell colSpan={2} align="center">
              {' '}
              RECUPERADAS
            </StyledTableCell>
            <StyledTableCell colSpan={2} align="center">
              {' '}
              SEM ATENDIMENTO
            </StyledTableCell>
          </TableRow>
          <TableRow>
            <StyledTableCell align="center">NOME</StyledTableCell>
            <StyledTableCell align="center">QTDE</StyledTableCell>
            <StyledTableCell align="center">QTDE</StyledTableCell>
            <StyledTableCell align="center">%</StyledTableCell>
            <StyledTableCell align="center">QTDE</StyledTableCell>
            <StyledTableCell align="center">%</StyledTableCell>
            <StyledTableCell align="center">QTDE</StyledTableCell>
            <StyledTableCell align="center">%</StyledTableCell>
            <StyledTableCell align="center">QTDE</StyledTableCell>
            <StyledTableCell align="center">%</StyledTableCell>
            <StyledTableCell align="center">QTDE</StyledTableCell>
            <StyledTableCell align="center">%</StyledTableCell>
            <StyledTableCell align="center">QTDE</StyledTableCell>
            <StyledTableCell align="center">%</StyledTableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        {rows !== undefined
          ? rows.map(rows => (
              <>
                <TableBody>
                  <StyledTableRow key={rows.label}>
                    <StyledTableCell component="th" scope="row">
                      <b>{rows.label}</b>
                    </StyledTableCell>
                    <StyledTableCell align="center">
                      <b>{rows.ligacoesRecebidasUtil}</b>
                    </StyledTableCell>
                    <StyledTableCell align="center">
                      <b>{rows.ligacoesAtendidas}</b>
                    </StyledTableCell>
                    <StyledTableCell align="center">
                      <b>{rows.percentualAtendidas}%</b>
                    </StyledTableCell>
                    <StyledTableCell align="center">
                      <b>{rows.ligacoesAbandonadasUtil}</b>
                    </StyledTableCell>
                    <StyledTableCell align="center">
                      <b>{rows.percentualAbandonadasUtil}%</b>
                    </StyledTableCell>
                    <StyledTableCell align="center">
                      <b>{rows.ligacoesAbandonadas}</b>
                    </StyledTableCell>
                    <StyledTableCell align="center">
                      <b>{rows.percentualAbandonadas}%</b>
                    </StyledTableCell>
                    <StyledTableCell align="center">
                      <b>{rows.ligacoesAtendidas}</b>
                    </StyledTableCell>
                    <StyledTableCell align="center">
                      <b>{rows.percentualAtendidas}%</b>
                    </StyledTableCell>
                    <StyledTableCell align="center">
                      <b>{rows.ligacoesAutoRecuperadas}</b>
                    </StyledTableCell>
                    <StyledTableCell align="center">
                      <b>{rows.percentualAutoRecuperadas}%</b>
                    </StyledTableCell>
                    <StyledTableCell align="center">
                      <b>{rows.ligacoesRecuperadas}</b>
                    </StyledTableCell>
                    <StyledTableCell align="center">
                      <b>{rows.percentualRecuperadas}%</b>
                    </StyledTableCell>
                  </StyledTableRow>
                </TableBody>
                <TableBody>
                  {!VBU && rows.filas !== undefined
                    ? rows.filas.map(rows => (
                        <StyledTableRow className={classes.sonRow} key={rows.label}>
                          <StyledTableCell
                            style={{ paddingLeft: '2vw' }}
                            component="th"
                            scope="row"
                          >
                            {rows.label}
                          </StyledTableCell>
                          <StyledTableCell align="center">
                            {rows.ligacoesRecebidasUtil}
                          </StyledTableCell>
                          <StyledTableCell align="center">
                            {rows.ligacoesAtendidas}
                          </StyledTableCell>
                          <StyledTableCell align="center">
                            {rows.percentualAtendidas}%
                          </StyledTableCell>
                          <StyledTableCell align="center">
                            {rows.ligacoesAbandonadasUtil}
                          </StyledTableCell>
                          <StyledTableCell align="center">
                            {rows.percentualAbandonadasUtil}%
                          </StyledTableCell>
                          <StyledTableCell align="center">
                            {rows.ligacoesAbandonadas}
                          </StyledTableCell>
                          <StyledTableCell align="center">
                            {rows.percentualAbandonadas}%
                          </StyledTableCell>
                          <StyledTableCell align="center">
                            {rows.ligacoesAtendidas}
                          </StyledTableCell>
                          <StyledTableCell align="center">
                            {rows.percentualAtendidas}%
                          </StyledTableCell>
                          <StyledTableCell align="center">
                            {rows.ligacoesAutoRecuperadas}
                          </StyledTableCell>
                          <StyledTableCell align="center">
                            {rows.percentualAutoRecuperadas}%
                          </StyledTableCell>
                          <StyledTableCell align="center">
                            {rows.ligacoesRecuperadas}
                          </StyledTableCell>
                          <StyledTableCell align="center">
                            {rows.percentualRecuperadas}%
                          </StyledTableCell>
                        </StyledTableRow>
                      ))
                    : VBU && operacao && rows.hosts !== undefined
                    ? rows.hosts.map(row => (
                        <StyledTableRow className={classes.sonRow} key={row.label}>
                          <StyledTableCell
                            style={{ paddingLeft: '2vw' }}
                            component="th"
                            scope="row"
                          >
                            {row.label}
                          </StyledTableCell>
                          <StyledTableCell align="center">
                            {row.ligacoesRecebidasUtil}
                          </StyledTableCell>
                          <StyledTableCell align="center">
                            {row.ligacoesAtendidas}
                          </StyledTableCell>
                          <StyledTableCell align="center">
                            {row.percentualAtendidas}%
                          </StyledTableCell>
                          <StyledTableCell align="center">
                            {row.ligacoesAbandonadasUtil}
                          </StyledTableCell>
                          <StyledTableCell align="center">
                            {row.percentualAbandonadasUtil}%
                          </StyledTableCell>
                          <StyledTableCell align="center">
                            {row.ligacoesAbandonadas}
                          </StyledTableCell>
                          <StyledTableCell align="center">
                            {row.percentualAbandonadas}%
                          </StyledTableCell>
                          <StyledTableCell align="center">
                            {row.ligacoesAtendidas}
                          </StyledTableCell>
                          <StyledTableCell align="center">
                            {row.percentualAtendidas}%
                          </StyledTableCell>
                          <StyledTableCell align="center">
                            {row.ligacoesAutoRecuperadas}
                          </StyledTableCell>
                          <StyledTableCell align="center">
                            {row.percentualAutoRecuperadas}%
                          </StyledTableCell>
                          <StyledTableCell align="center">
                            {row.ligacoesRecuperadas}
                          </StyledTableCell>
                          <StyledTableCell align="center">
                            {row.percentualRecuperadas}%
                          </StyledTableCell>
                        </StyledTableRow>
                      ))
                    : VBU && !operacao && rows.regionais !== undefined
                    ? rows.regionais.map(row => (
                        <StyledTableRow className={classes.sonRow} key={row.label}>
                          <StyledTableCell
                            style={{ paddingLeft: '2vw' }}
                            component="th"
                            scope="row"
                          >
                            {row.label}
                          </StyledTableCell>
                          <StyledTableCell align="center">
                            {row.ligacoesRecebidasUtil}
                          </StyledTableCell>
                          <StyledTableCell align="center">
                            {row.ligacoesAtendidas}
                          </StyledTableCell>
                          <StyledTableCell align="center">
                            {row.percentualAtendidas}%
                          </StyledTableCell>
                          <StyledTableCell align="center">
                            {row.ligacoesAbandonadasUtil}
                          </StyledTableCell>
                          <StyledTableCell align="center">
                            {row.percentualAbandonadasUtil}%
                          </StyledTableCell>
                          <StyledTableCell align="center">
                            {row.ligacoesAbandonadas}
                          </StyledTableCell>
                          <StyledTableCell align="center">
                            {row.percentualAbandonadas}%
                          </StyledTableCell>
                          <StyledTableCell align="center">
                            {row.ligacoesAtendidas}
                          </StyledTableCell>
                          <StyledTableCell align="center">
                            {row.percentualAtendidas}%
                          </StyledTableCell>
                          <StyledTableCell align="center">
                            {row.ligacoesAutoRecuperadas}
                          </StyledTableCell>
                          <StyledTableCell align="center">
                            {row.percentualAutoRecuperadas}%
                          </StyledTableCell>
                          <StyledTableCell align="center">
                            {row.ligacoesRecuperadas}
                          </StyledTableCell>
                          <StyledTableCell align="center">
                            {row.percentualRecuperadas}%
                          </StyledTableCell>
                        </StyledTableRow>
                      ))
                    : null}
                </TableBody>
              </>
            ))
          : null}
        {/* <div
          style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-between', border: '0' }}
        > */}
        <IconButton onClick={() => handleOnExport()}>
          <GetApp />
        </IconButton>
        <TableFooter>
          <TableRow>
            <TablePagination
              rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 25, { label: 'Todos', value: -1 }]}
              colSpan={3}
              count={lines}
              rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
              page={page}
              SelectProps={{
                inputProps: {
                  'aria-label': 'rows per page',
                },
                native: true,
              }}
              onPageChange={handleChangePage}
              onRowsPerPageChange={handleChangeRowsPerPage}
              ActionsComponent={TablePaginationActions}
            />
          </TableRow>
        </TableFooter>
      </Table>
      {/* </div> */}
    </TableContainer>
```

I even tried to mount all my items in one array without objects, but it doesnt work too, could someone tell me if im doing a bad use of mui's tablepagination?

Answer (score 0):

Discovered the answer, I was forgetting the line before my tags

```
(rowsPerPage > 0
      ? rows.slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage)
      : rows
    ).map(rows => (
      <>
        {rows !== null ? (
          rows.detalhes !== undefined ? (
            <TableBody key={rows.label}>
              <StyledTableRow
                classes={{ root: tabling.myCustomRoot }}
                key={rows.label}
              >
```